# In terms of application running time, is putting array elements on the root of UserDefaults preferred than putting them in container key?

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

I have an array of chat threads, which each also has array of chat messages.

```
Thread 1: "Hello world."
Participant: Alex, Billy, Cherry
Alex = "Hello"
Billy = "World"
Cherry = "Hahaha"

Thread 2: personal chat
Participants: Alex, Daniel
Alex = "Gday mate!"
Daniel = "Hey, how is it going?"
Alex = "Cool, lots of fun!"
```

I want to save this in `UserDefaults`. All of these will be saved in form of dictionaries and arrays.

Now imagine structure like this with thousands of threads and millions of messages. Then imagine I have to save it on the `UserDefaults`. Which way is better for me in saving these information?

Method 1: Save everything under one key `"threads"`. In this method, I have to load everything and save everything each time I add/change/delete even one message or thread.

```
{
    "threads": [
        {
            "id":90, "title":"Hello World", "participants":[7,12,54],
            "messages": [
                { "id":827, "sender":7, "text":"Hello" },
                { "id":828, "sender":12, "text":"World" },
                { "id":836, "sender":7, "text":"Hahaha" }
                ...
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "id":92, "title":"", "participants":[7,9],
            "messages": [
                { "id":850, "sender":7, "text":"Gday mate!" },
                { "id":855, "sender":12, "text":"Hey, how is it going?" },
                { "id":861, "sender":7, "text":"Cool, lot's of fun!" }
                ...
            ]
        }
        ...
    ]
}
```

Method 2: Break down the threads into elements, and save them one by one on the root. This way I'll only operating with one key at a time. Still have the original "threads" key though, to know what thread entries do I have. But that means the key on the the root level is going to be massive (the phone needs to load all the root key each time I tried to access UserDefaults?), and I'm not only going to have just chats to save.

```
{
    "threads": [ 90, 92, ... ],
    "thread-90": {
        "id":90, "title":"Hello World", "participants":[7,12,54],
        "messages": [
            { "id":827, "sender":7, "text":"Hello" },
            { "id":828, "sender":12, "text":"World" },
            { "id":836, "sender":7, "text":"Hahaha" }
            ...
        ]
    },
    "thread-92": {
        "id":92, "title":"", "participants":[7,9],
        "messages": [
            { "id":850, "sender":7, "text":"Gday mate!" },
            { "id":855, "sender":12, "text":"Hey, how is it going?" },
            { "id":861, "sender":7, "text":"Cool, lot's of fun!" }
            ...
        ]
    }
    ...
}
```

Which one is better in the long run in terms of access speed, application performance, and CPU load, if all of these will be accessed quite frequent? I don't know how significant the loading time is if it's from `UserDefaults`.

Comment: Use `UserDefaults` for user defaults and preferences. Use Core Data or a database engine for a lot of data.

Comment: @Willeke oh ok, all this time, I thought Core Data was the same as UserDefaults, or at least use same approach. I'll do research on it. Thanks.